# Missing some Unicode glyphs on Windows 7, is there way to fix/patch it?

Tags: windows-7, fonts, unicode

I have an `arrowsbe.txt` file, with the following content (in hex):

```
FE FF 00 41 00 42 00 43 2B A1 00 20 2B A2
```

You see, it is UTF-16BE encoded, with BOM at file start. There are two not-so-often seen Unicode characters in it, U+2BA1 and U+2BA2.

On my Windows 7, those two Unicode glyphs each displays as a hollow box with a question mark in it.

[image: Windows 7 showing U+2BA1 and U+2BA2 as boxes]

On Windows 10 (21H2), they display correctly.

[image: Windows 10 showing U+2BA1 and U+2BA2 correctly]

This is not a matter of font selection. I have tried Arial, Tahoma, Segoe UI, SimSun etc, the results are the same, except that… some fonts display the hollow box without a question mark in it.

Is there way to display those two Unicode glyphs in Windows 7 Notepad? Perhaps by installing some special .TTF font file?

BTW: On Windows 7, those two boxed glyphs does not show up in other applications as well, e.g., Explorer address bar, Internet Explorer 11 text area, Chrome 109 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact that the default font set in Windows 7 does not support these characters.

You must install a third-party font, such as Code2000, Symbola, and Unifont; these all support these Unicode characters. Once this font is installed select it in Notepad, and these characters should display correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried Symbola and GNU Unifont, they do provide U+2BA1 and U+2BA2, and now they display well in Notepad. Code2000 does not have those two yet.